# PHP - json - function call issue

Tags: php, json, function

I am having two functions `printBefore(json1)` and `printAfter(json2)`.
Both are having json object as `parameter.jsons` are coming from database. They are parsing json and displaying it in correct format.
But it is taking more than 30 seconds.

When I removed functon and displays json as it is. It is not taking time more than second.

I am not able isolate problem. Please Help.

```
foreach ($records as $record) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $userNames['users'][$record->uid] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $userNames['users'][$record->uid] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $record->val . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $record->mi. '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $record->created_on . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . printBefore($record->newData) . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . printAfter($record->oldData) . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
```

Code for printAfter($oldData)

```
 $oldData = json_decode($oldData, true);
  if (isset($OldData['sub_category'])) {
        $str = $str . "|Category : " . $this->category[$OldData['sub_category']] . "|";
    }
```

code for PrintBefore($newData)

```
 $newData = json_decode($newData, true);
  if (isset($newData['sub_category'])) {
        $str = $str . "|Category : " . $this->category[$newData['sub_category']] . "|";
    }
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: what should we do without seeing a piece of your code??

Comment: I tried to seperate it from project and I execute it in seperate file, but still it is taking time

Comment: @Bludream : Code Provided now

Comment: It might takes time to search in your array.